# Does Facelets rebuild the whole page if Ajax is trigger from a form and updates another?

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2

Setup:
I have 2 forms A & B
I have a commandLink in form A:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{homeView.selectDiv('homeUpdates')}">#{msg.homeUpdates}
   <f:ajax render=":B" execute="@this" />
</h:commandLink>
```

...which updates form B.

The problem is that when I click the ajax link, it rebuilds form A as well and gets an exception from a ui:repeat I have. Is this correct behaviour? Should it rebuild form A as well?

I am using JSF 2.2 and form A contains a ui:fragment=>ui:include=>ui:repeat

=====Added SSCCE=======
The following code does not run after pressing Update B! twice. It gives an exception of duplicate id. The value for ui:repeat is irrelevant

```
<h:head>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form id="A">
        <ul class="tableView notification">
            <ui:repeat var="notification" value="#{dashboardBean.notifications}">
                <li>
                    xx
                </li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>

        <h:commandLink value="Update B!" listener="#{dashboardBean.toggleRendered}">
            <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":B" />
        </h:commandLink>

    </h:form>

    <h:form id="B">
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Extra hint: If I modify render to -":A :B" then the error goes away. It appears that for some reason, the 'execute' triggers a rebuilt of the form and for some other weird reason it add ui:repeat again (with the same id), which gives me the following error:
Component ID navigation_form:uif1 has already been found in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon initial request the **view is created**, upon postbacks the view is restored. To recite some points of [JSF 2.2 specification](https://javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/) for clarity (emphasis mine):

**P. 2.2.1**:

> If the request is not a postback ... call **createView()** on the ViewHandler. If the request is a postback, ... call ViewHandler.**restoreView()**, passing the FacesContext instance for the current request and the view identifier, and returning a UIViewRoot for the restored view.

**P. 2.5.8**:

> **Selected** components in a JSF view can be priocessed (known as partial processing) and **selected** components can be rendered to the client (known as partial rendering).

**P. 13.4**:

> The JavaServer Faces lifecycle, can be viewed as consisting of an execute phase and a render phase. Partial traversal is the technique that can be used to “visit” one or more components in the view, potentially to have them pass through the “execute” and/or “render” phases of the request processing lifecycle.

When you use AJAX, `PartialViewContext` class will contain all the information that's needed to traverse the restored view.

---

So, to get back to your question, under `<f:ajax render=":B" execute="@this" />` setup, **only the form with `id="B"` will be rerendered**, which implies `<h:form id="B">`, no form nestings, etc.

Regarding your 'doesn't work' comment the simple test case with a plain view scoped managed bean gave me the expected results:

```
<h:form id="A" >
    <h:outputText value="#{twoFormsBean.a}"/>
    <h:commandLink actionListener="#{twoFormsBean.actionA}">
        Update B!
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":B"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
<h:form id="B" >
    <h:outputText value="#{twoFormsBean.b}"/>
    <h:commandLink>
        Update Both!
        <f:ajax execute="@this" render=":A :B"/>
    </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TwoFormsBean implements Serializable {

    private String a = "A";//getter
    private String b = "B";//getter

    public void actionA(ActionEvent ae) {
        a = "newA";
        b = "newB";
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is aligned with my expectations on how it should work, so thank you for compiled details. I managed to identify the critical/breaking factor which is that in form A I have a composite component(defined as an .xhtml under WebContent/resources/components). If I remove this from within the ui:repeat everything works at it should. When I put it back it breaks.

    <ul>
    <ui:repeat var="notification" value="#dashboardBean.notifications}">
    <li>              <jid1:notification notification="#{notification}" />
    </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>

Comment: You need to provide for a SSCCE so that we'd be able to reproduce your problem. And welcome!

Comment: Restore view in case of Facelets builds the view again from scratch and then applies the view state (if any).