# Use commandLink to update parent table that is child to another table

Tags: ajax, jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2

I have this structure:

```
<h:dataTable id="baselist">
   <h:dataTable id=childlist">
       <p:commandLink update="should only update childlist">
   </h:dataTable>
</h:dataTable>
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but I only get errors saying that the `childlist` can not be found. Is it not possible to update this way?

Comment: You can try `update="@parent"`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the there is an index number included in the id of the childlist datatable.

**eg.:**

the id of the childlist table in the first row of the parent table is: `:form:baselist:0:childlist`

the id of the childlist table in the second row of the parent table is: `:form:baselist:1:childlist`

the id of the childlist table in the third row of the parent table is: `:form:baselist:2:childlist`

and so on...

**Solution:**

Update the parent table so everything gets updated and synchronized including childlist tables in all the rows

**eg.**

`update=":form:baselist"`

**Unrealated:**

You can see the full qualified id of your elements by right clicking your rendered page in the browser and view page source.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that and it works; my question though, is why I'm not able to only update the child table. I've tried: `@parent` which does not update anything it would seem; and also the full qualified path which gives the exception about the id not possible to find, even though I can see it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

You may can try using `#{component.parent.clientId}` but you wouldn't be gaining as much as you think.

JSF will typically rebuild the whole structure see answer in: [Does Facelets rebuild the whole page if Ajax is trigger from a form and updates another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234805/does-facelets-rebuild-the-whole-page-if-ajax-is-trigger-from-a-form-and-updates)

In addition, if you have modified `baselist`, then you will get into problems as the `:0,:1` namingcontainer ids will become inconsistent.
e.g. if you remove the first element from `baselist`, JSF will rebuid the view with new ids.
so `:form:baselist:1:childlist'` will become `:form:baselist:0:childlist` etc.

I am not sure if you 'll get an error but for sure this will cause some pain sooner or later.