# Migrate jsf application to Glassfish 4 and JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf-2.2, glassfish-4

I moved a JSF application from Galssfish 3.1.2 to **Glassfish 4.0** and I thought the new server  release was completely back compatible.

I found out it is not.

I used an outdated library, Primefaces 2.X, and some components stopped working properly, at least **<p:tabview>**. Common sense suggests to pass to a newer library such as Primafaces 3.5, but that way I have to modify my xhtml pages. Cannot find a compatibility matrix anywhere, nor a migration tutorial. Can you help ?

There is at least another weird problem outside those related to the Primefaces library.

I have a quite complex page and till now I couldn't isolate the problem to a simpler scenario.
In this page I have an **<ui:repeat>** tag and then a form with a button.
The button is configured to send Ajax request and update (render) only a single ui component.
At the 3rd Ajax request it stops working and I get an error saying there is a duplicate ID corresponding to the **<ui:repeat>** tag.
Any idea ?

Is there a migration guide from Glassfish 3.1.2 to Glassfish 4.0 which gives hints on what has changed and how to modify existing applications ?

Update 
I found the following post which deals about the last problem I'm talkin about
[Component ID xxx has already been found in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234805/does-facelets-rebuild-the-whole-page-if-ajax-is-trigger-from-a-form-and-updates).

Unfortunately I cannot understand how to solve it despite it has an accepted answer !

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the many bugs that were released with GF4.

I would suggest either waiting for the next release of GF (if you need a released version) or update GF to the latest JSF release (Currently 2.2.8 I think).

[JSF implementation jars](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/2.2/download.html)

[JEE7 APIs](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/Java+EE+7+Maven+Coordinates)

[JSF current and older bugs](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES/)